# BigQuery Results Not Including Page Token

Tags: python, google-bigquery

We're working on the `pandas.io.gbq` and we are noticing some unusual behaviour for large results sets. The code works roughly as follows (where `bq` is from [bq.py](http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/browse/bq/bigquery_client.py)). The first few pages of data return valid pageTokens, but after that every couple returns none. A trimmed copy of the JSON returned can be viewed at:
https://gist.github.com/jacobschaer/8309204

```
import bq
import bigquery_client
#.
#.
#.
client = bq.Client.Get()
kwds = {'timeoutMs': 0, u'projectId': u'xxxxxxx', 'startIndex': 0, 'maxResults': 1000000, u'jobId': u'bqjob_r36320b28158a7c96_000001436eb0431c_1'}
data = client.apiclient.jobs().getQueryResults(**kwds).execute()
```

This might be related to: [BigQuery paging issues with tableData.list()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547011/bigquery-paging-issues-with-tabledata-list)

Ultimately, we are winding up with duplicates in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

I can help you get to the bottom of this. The snippet of code above kicks of the fetching the first set of query results and should produce a page token. It sounds like it's the subsequent calls where you're running an into an issue - can you show me how you are making the subsequent calls?

Could you clarify something for me as well, you also mentioned that the first few pages return valid page tokens and then every couple pages return none. Did you mean you are getting pages that contain no pagetokens at all? Or did you mean there are pages that contain a valid page token but no results?

Comment: Sorry, the code snippet was quite small just to give you a feeling of the API Client call we're making. The full code we're using is available at:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/gbq.py

I would like to clarify that the `bq` command line client is having the same problem. I added some logging into `bigquery_client.py` and ran a query:
`bq -q query -n 999999999 --format=csv 'SELECT * FROM analysis_temp.500k_with_row_numbers'`
(analysis_temp.500k_with_row_numbers) is a subset of the Wikipedia data.

The results can be seen at:
https://gist.github.com/jacobschaer/8337318

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'll have an update for you soon.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the client logic around reading rows. The loop in the bq client alternates between using page_tokens and trying to count rows.  The client code change isn't released yet - but here's a short summary:

Comment: Basically, whenever the page token is missing there are no more results and iteration should end. When the page token came up empty instead of stopping we fallback onto the start index which we're supposed to be keeping track of. The bug in the released client was that start index was only updated when the page_token was missing - so it was basically never right, when you hit the end of the iteration and got an empty pagetoken, we'd use the (wrong) start index and start returning results from wherever start index was.

Comment: One odd thing about the logs w/ page tokens you'd showed was many of the page tokens repeat - that's odd because page tokens are supposed to be unique. 

I'm not sure how you produced those given the code in gbq.py - but if you were getting a single page of results over and over again by requesting the same start_row that could explain it.

Comment: I still don't see a fix pushed to http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/list

Comment: Talking to Eric - server side has been fixed (that should fix the issue), and improvements to the client side are coming out (but not needed). Client side will surface errors when server doesn't include a token - which should not happen again.